# WPF | Implementar paneo y zoom con el teclado y mouse en PDFViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

He estado haciendo un visor de PDF para poder dibujarle líneas, polígonos, áreas, etc, pero investigando, no hay nada que no sea de pago, pero encontré una opción que se usa con las APIs de windows 10, tal y como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo

[PDF Viewer con Windows 10](https://blogs.u2u.be/lander/post/2018/01/23/Creating-a-PDF-Viewer-in-WPF-using-Windows-10-APIs)

Básicamente lo que se hace en el link, es que convierte el pdf a imágenes y las despliega en un `ScrollViewer` pero para poder modificar o manipular el pdf, creo un canvas antes y al canvas le añado las imágenes y así despliega las hojas del pdf para poder manipularlo

Para agregarle el paneo y el zoom encontré un proyecto en GitHub que lo hace sobre un control Canvas

[WPFPanAndZoom](https://github.com/SEilers/WpfPanAndZoom)

El zoom y el paneo se hacen en los eventos `MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove, MouseWheel`.
Tengo una clase llamada `PdfViewer.xaml.cs` en la que le implementé estos eventos pero en el `MouseWheel` no detectaba mi scroll, asi que lo cambie a `PreviewMouseWheel` y ahí detectó el evento, y este fué mi resultado

[image]

Cada vez que hago Scroll, la imagen actual se hace chica y se pierde y tengo que hacer zoom hasta que la encuentro

El resultado esperado (es el editor xaml de Visual Studio):

[image]

Mi duda es, como puedo implementar el paneo y el zoom como el editor de xaml de Visual Studio, o al menos algo parecido sin que se me deforme o se me pierda el PDF?

Esta es mi clase `PdfViewer.xaml.cs`

```
//MainWindow.xaml
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <controls:PdfViewer PdfPath="example.pdf"/>
</Grid>

//PdfViewer.xaml
    <UserControl ... Background="DarkGray">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroll" PanningMode="Both" Background="DarkGray">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="PagesContainer"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </UserControl>

//PdfViewer class
public class ImageTag
{
    public PdfViewer Viewer;
    public Canvas? Canvas;
    public uint PageID;

    public ImageTag(PdfViewer viewer, uint pageID, Canvas? canvas)
    {
        Viewer = viewer;
        PageID = pageID;
        Canvas = canvas;
    }
}

public partial class PdfViewer : UserControl
{
    ImageTag? CurrentImage { get; set; }
    private readonly MatrixTransform _transform = new MatrixTransform();
    private Point _initialMousePosition;

    private bool _dragging;
    private UIElement? _selectedElement;
    private Vector _draggingDelta;
    public float Zoomfactor { get; set; } = 1.1f;

    public string PdfPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PdfPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PdfPathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PdfPathProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PdfPath", typeof(string), typeof(PdfViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null, propertyChangedCallback: OnPdfPathChanged));


    public PdfViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MouseDown += PdfViewer_MouseDown;
        MouseUp += PdfViewer_MouseUp;
        MouseMove += PdfViewer_MouseMove;
        //MouseWheel += PdfViewer_MouseWheel;
        PreviewMouseWheel += PdfViewer_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    internal void Navigate(uint page)
    {
        double offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < page && i < PagesContainer.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            double itemHeight = (PagesContainer.Items[i] as Canvas)!.ActualHeight + 4;
            offset += itemHeight;
        }
        Scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset);
    }

    private static void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is Image image)
        {
            ImageTag? tag = image.Tag as ImageTag;
            tag!.Viewer.CurrentImage = tag;
        }
    }

    private async static Task PdfToImages(PdfViewer pdfViewer, PdfDocument pdfDoc)
    {
        ItemCollection items = pdfViewer.PagesContainer.Items;
        items.Clear();

        if (pdfDoc == null) return;

        for (uint i = 0; i < pdfDoc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            using var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
            var bitmap = await PageToBitmapAsync(page);
            var canvas = new Canvas()
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 4, 0, 4),
                MaxWidth = 800,
                Width = bitmap.PixelWidth,
                Height = bitmap.PixelHeight
            };
            var image = new Image
            {
                Source = bitmap,
                Tag = new ImageTag(pdfViewer, i, canvas), // Tag page number
            };
            image.MouseDown += Image_MouseDown;
            canvas?.Children.Add(image);
            items.Add(canvas);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<BitmapImage> PageToBitmapAsync(PdfPage page)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new();
        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);

            image.BeginInit();
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.StreamSource = stream.AsStream();
            image.EndInit();
        }
        return image;
    }

    private void PdfViewer_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
        {
            _initialMousePosition = _transform.Inverse.Transform(e.GetPosition(this));
        }

        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            if (CurrentImage!.Canvas!.Children.Contains((UIElement)e.Source))
            {
                _selectedElement = (UIElement)e.Source;
                Point mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
                double x = Canvas.GetLeft(_selectedElement);
                double y = Canvas.GetTop(_selectedElement);
                Point elementPosition = new(x, y);
                _draggingDelta = elementPosition - mousePosition;
            }
            _dragging = true;
        }
    }

    private void PdfViewer_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _dragging = false;
        _selectedElement = null;
    }

    private void PdfViewer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Point mousePosition = _transform.Inverse.Transform(e.GetPosition(this));
            Vector delta = Point.Subtract(mousePosition, _initialMousePosition);
            var translate = new TranslateTransform(delta.X, delta.Y);
            _transform.Matrix = translate.Value * _transform.Matrix;

            foreach (UIElement child in CurrentImage!.Canvas!.Children)
            {
                child.RenderTransform = _transform;
            }
        }

        if (_dragging && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            double x = Mouse.GetPosition(this).X;
            double y = Mouse.GetPosition(this).Y;

            if (_selectedElement != null)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(_selectedElement, x + _draggingDelta.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(_selectedElement, y + _draggingDelta.Y);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PdfViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        float scaleFactor = Zoomfactor;
        if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            scaleFactor = 1f / scaleFactor;
        }

        Point mousePostion = e.GetPosition(this);

        Matrix scaleMatrix = _transform.Matrix;
        scaleMatrix.ScaleAt(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, mousePostion.X, mousePostion.Y);
        _transform.Matrix = scaleMatrix;

        if (CurrentImage == null) return;

        foreach (UIElement child in CurrentImage!.Canvas!.Children)
        {
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(child);
            double y = Canvas.GetTop(child);

            double sx = x * scaleFactor;
            double sy = y * scaleFactor;

            Canvas.SetLeft(child, sx);
            Canvas.SetTop(child, sy);

            child.RenderTransform = _transform;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En base a experiencia de otros desarrolladores que conozco, para soluciones así, es preferible invertir en la adquisición de esas librerías que ya tienen varias cosas funcionando.

Comment: @fredyfx gracias, si es lo mas viable en este caso, gracias de antemano, y perdón por responder en 2024 jaja, nunca revisé las notificaciones